# div doesn't position horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im not getting my form element to position horizontaly in the center here is my code

```
$('.form') 
.css('top', window.screen.availHeight / 2 - $('.form').height() / 2)
```

Comment: can you make an example of this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: What is the value of `display` css attribute of your `.form`?

Comment: I haven't set the display attribute

Comment: Is `$(".form")` correct? Should it be `$("form")`? Including the HTML would help here.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure it's `position: absolute;` as @[Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119271/douglas) points out.  Past that, you're fetching the *screen* height, as in the entire monitor, not the browser window.  Instead of `window.screen.availHeight`, you likely just want `$(window).height()`, like this:

```
$('.form').css('top', $(window).height() / 2 - $('.form').height() / 2);
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/r6TNU/).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the top property with css won't affect the horizontal position of the element.

Setting `top` (or `left` for horizontal positioning) will not have an effect if the position of the element is set to `static`, which is the default.

Try position absolute instead:

```
.form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I've set the position to absolute i don't get the desired results

Comment: @littleMan: Could you include the html you are using, as well as the values you get for `window.screen.availHeight` and `$('.form').height()`? Write them to the console using `console.log(...)`.